# enqueue multiple GET request when using nested retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, request, retrofit2

I am using `Retrofit 2.0` to make api calls with nesting multiple requests. All api's works fine individually. 
But when i nested all retrofit, First request execute perfectly but after that when i register second request it's not callback in `enqueue` method (i.e. it's directly returning `null` without inserting `enqueue's` inner methods like `onResponse`, `onFailure`)

My Code :-

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Gson gson;
    JSONObject jsonResult=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        gson=new GsonBuilder().create();
        firstRequest(); //-- First retrofit request
    }


    private void firstRequest() {
        Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(getResources().getString(R.string.Api_Url)).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();
        CityRetailsApi service = retrofit.create(CityRetailsApi.class);
        Call call_first= service.getMainCatFlag();

        call_first.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {        
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Status Code = " + response.code());
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    MainCatFlag result = (MainCatFlag) response.body(); //-- Get First request response                    
                    JSONObject json2nd = secondRequest(); //-- Second request
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Error");
            }
        });
    }

    private JSONObject secondRequest() {
        try {            
            Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(getResources().getString(R.string.Api_Url)).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();
            CityRetailsApi service = retrofit.create(CityRetailsApi.class);
            Call call_second= service.getMainCat();

            call_second.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call2, Response response1) {                    
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Status Code = " + response1.code());
                    if (response1.isSuccessful()) {                        
                        MainCat result = (MainCat) response1.body();
                        if (result.getSuccess()==1)
                        {
                            try {
                                jsonResult= new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(result));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Error");
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Error= " + e);
        }
        return jsonResult;
    }
}
```

In above code `firstRequest()` executed correctly and proving response but the `secondRequest` (inside firstRequest() enqueue method) not working fine. Not showing any error, success message in console. Can any one please help me to override this problem.

If any problem in my code, please let me know.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you run the debugger to ensure that response.isSuccessful is true?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, it's returning me Successful status and also goes to my secondRequest() function. But my problem is it's not executing call_second.enqueue(.....) method.

Comment: Sorry I'm honestly stumped everything looks right to me. I have similar code the only thing I do differently is my callbacks are not anonymous inner classes so maybe that makes a difference even though it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake that when you using retrofit enquene,it's called **asynchronously**, so you can't get the result outside of the callback method!

So, you should process your result inside the **onResponse** method like this:

```
private void secondRequest() {
    try {             
        call_second.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override 
            public void onResponse(Call call2, Response response1) {                    
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Status Code = " + response1.code());
                if (response1.isSuccessful()) {                        
                    MainCat result = (MainCat) response1.body();
                    if (result.getSuccess()==1)
                    { 
                        try { 
                            jsonResult= new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(result));

                            // process your jsonResult here
                            ...

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            } 

            @Override 
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Error");
            } 
        }); 
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Error= " + e);
    } 
}
```